# OSX: Copying files to folders with same name

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm looking for a script of some sort, to copy about 800 files with separate case numbers ex: "1234567 - XXXX XXX" of which is placed in one folder, into a directory of another folder(a server) with the same case name, under a subfolder ex:

"1234567 - XXXX XXX/01_Management/01_Correspondence" (subfolder identical for all folders)

Sum up: Copying one file, to another folder with the same name as the file, placing it in a subfolder.

macOS Sierra

Thank you
-Theis

Comment: Do the target directories already exist where the files must be copied to? Do the filenames always have precisely one multi-digit number (no letters) followed by a space then a hyphen?

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with a `bash` script.

Make a back-up first!

Save the following in your HOME directory as `reorganise`:

```
#!/bin/bash

find $(pwd) -name "* -*" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' f; do
   echo Processing file $f...
   base=$(basename "$f")
   echo "   base: $base"
   case=${base/ -*/}
   echo "   case: $case"
   # EDIT THE FOLLOWING LINE TO BE CORRECT FOR YOU !!!
   newplace="/path/to/new/place/$case"
   echo mkdir -p "$newplace"
   echo cp "$f" "$newplace"
done
```

Then start `Terminal` and type the following just once to make the script executable:

```
chmod +x reorganise
```

Then go to the directory where your files are:

```
cd where/your/files/are
```

And then you can run the script with:

```
$HOME/organise
```

and it will tell you what it would do, without doing anything. If you like it, you can remove the word `echo` on the second and third to last lines and run it again.

You will need to edit the indicated line at least.

**Sample Output**

```
Processing file /Users/mark/tmp/1234563 - fredb...
   base: 1234563 - fredb
   case: 1234563
mkdir -p /path/to/new/place/1234563
cp /Users/mark/tmp/1234563 - fredb /path/to/new/place/1234563
Processing file /Users/mark/tmp/1234567 - fred...
   base: 1234567 - fred
   case: 1234567
mkdir -p /path/to/new/place/1234567
cp /Users/mark/tmp/1234567 - fred /path/to/new/place/1234567
```